# VBA to save document in Excel and Word periodically (AutoBackup)

Tags: microsoft-excel, backup, microsoft-word, vba

I want to create a VBA script that would save a copy of the document every 5-10 minutes with a new name. The script would keep like 10-15 copies in the same folder, incrementing a number each time. If it reaches the max number of saves, it should delete the oldest one.

For example:

```
document.xlsx - Working copy.  
document_b1.xlsx - First backup, done after 5 minutes.  
document_b2.xlsx - Second backup, after 10 minutes.
```

And so on, and so on.
When this number at the end reaches 15, the script should rename the rest.
i.e.:

```
document_b15 - gets deleted.  
document_b14 -> document_b15  
document_b13 -> document_b14  
...  
document_b1 - new copy.
```

What kind of function could do the steps required?
A short list the VBA would need:

- Incrementing a valuable
- Renaming files
- Deleting file
- Saving the current document as a new file

I'm aware that the Q belongs to Stackoverflow. Regarding the programming part.
But I want to use an existing solution, rather than learning VBA from scratch.

**Is there a VBA that would do this for me?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a quick auto-backup add-in for Excel.
Can you please test it and report your bugs? I will improve it if necessary.

**Installation**

1. Download the [Add-In](http://ge.tt/78ZHytV/v/0)
2. save it at `C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Microsoft\AddIns\`
3. Open Excel and navigate to
   (Excel 2003) Menubar → Tools → Add-ins
   (Excel 2007) Start-button → Excel Options → Add-Ins → drop down: Excel add-ins → Go
   (Excel 2010) File tab → Options → Add-Ins → drop down: Excel add-ins → Go
4. check *myautobackup*

**What it does**

- saves a backup file for each open workbook
- a new folder called *autobackup* is created at the same place as the workbook
- up to 3 backups are saved there
- save date is appended to original backup file name
- time interval is 10 seconds
- newly created workbooks which aren't saved yet by the user aren't saved by autobackup
  (They have no valid path yet)
- source code (34 lines) can be viewed on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mkbn4ZXe).
  Additionally an [open-event](http://pastebin.com/LQPcL1sU) will start the auto backup

<sup>Note: These low time delay and count settings are only for early testing. You can easily. change them later</sup>

[image]

Comment: Sounds great! You should really make a github page for the script. I mean... a lot of people would love to have a great addon.